# Docker public network configuration

Tags: networking, docker, external, public

I have 1 host with ip 10.120.194.214/24

And I have a range set from my router to my host ip, the range is 10.120.187.0/24 and his gateway is 10.120.187.1

I'm trying to create a docker network with this range

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=10.120.187.0/24 --ip-    range=10.120.187.128/25 --gateway=10.120.187.254 -o     "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc=true" -o     "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4"="10.120.187.1" mypublicnet
```

if I try to ping to 10.120.187.254 from the LAN i don't receive ping

the host configuration is this

iface eth0 inet manual

```
auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
address 10.120.194.214
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.120.194.1
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0
dns-nameservers 10.120.194.1 10.120.194.10
```

The idea is that I can run containers with ip accesible from the LAN, Every container must have diferent ip.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what you think, docker bridge network is not bridged to the physical interface, but is NATed.

To achieve what you are asking for in production, use [Pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework) or, if you are cutting edge, you can try the [docker macvlan driver](http://hicu.be/docker-networking-macvlan-bridge-mode-configuration) which is, for now, experimental.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. if I use pipework i won't have the auto IP assignement that docker network have, as far as I see you create an ethernet device inside the container and assign the IP but i want the ip will be auto assigned depends on which ips are free

Comment: With pipework, [you can use DHCP to assign IP addresses](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework#dhcp).